# Style border Excel using ClosedXML in C#

Tags: excel, closedxml

I have a table data in Excel

[image]

I want to apply style broder as image
[image]

How to code script in C# using ClosedXML?

Comment: ClosedXML documentation about borders are available at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Styles-Border . I want to urge you to read through all the ClosedXML documentation. It will answer a lot of questions that you will encounter as you learn ClosedXML.

Comment: ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.TopBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.InsideBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Dotted;
ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.OutsideBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.LeftBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.RightBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.TopBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank  @Francois Botha! I try it and it work. :)

> ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.TopBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
>   ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.InsideBorder =
>   XLBorderStyleValues.Dotted;
>   ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.OutsideBorder =
>   XLBorderStyleValues.Thin; ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.LeftBorder =
>   XLBorderStyleValues.Thin; ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.RightBorder =
>   XLBorderStyleValues.Thin; ws.Range("A1:D4").Style.Border.TopBorder =
>   XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
worksheet.Range(1,1,4,4).Style
          .Border.SetOutsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin)
          .Border.SetInsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin);
```